# What does a preamble look like in the definition of an IEEE 802.15.4 frame?

Tags: ieee

If you look under the section "802.15.4 Frame Format" on [this page](http://infopoort.nl/index.php/Components%3aAT86RF233) you will see it defines

```
Preamble Sequence : 4 octets 
Start Frame Delimiter (SFD) : 1 octet
```

In the [AT86RF233's data sheet](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDoQFjAA&url=http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8351-MCU_Wireless-AT86RF233_Datasheet.pdf&ei=oxXnUZTyOsL84AOR8YDIDw&usg=AFQjCNEtfMu4Hza-C2OtA8Kq1MzDdeJrxQ&sig2=7nkdkmo-hCA4L4Dhlyfdhg&bvm=bv.49405654,d.dmg) on pg. 76 Section 8.1.1.1 in the SFD is predefined to be

```
0xA7
```

But the preamble does not have a predefined value, so what should I define it to be? I don't see any indication in the data sheet explaining this further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [AT86RF233 data sheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8351-mcu_wireless-at86rf233_datasheet.pdf) (p.76):

> 8.1.1 PHY Protocol Data Unit (PPDU)
>
> 8.1.1.1 Synchronization Header (SHR)
>
> The SHR consists of a four-octet preamble field (all zero), followed by a single byte
>   start-of-frame delimiter (SFD) which has the predefined value 0xA7. During transmission, the SHR is automatically generated by the Atmel AT86RF233, thus the Frame Buffer shall contain PHR and PSDU only, see Section 6.3.2. […]

So, to me it looks like the preamble is made of 32 consecutive Zero-Bits. However, I am curious why you need to "define" the preamble, as it is automatically generated by the hardware and cannot be modified by configuration.